# Is there a better way to handle combination of two bool conditions?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have method with two parameters: bool1 and bool2. Both are boolean of course. I have to handle in code every combination of these conditions. Is any better way to do it then using nested if / else :

```
if (bool1)
{
    if(bool2)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
else
{
    if(bool2)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You have four distinct conditions, yes? This is probably the cleanest way you could write it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (bool1 && bool2) { }
else if (bool1) {}
else if (bool2) {}
else {}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var bothAreTrue = bool1 && bool2;

if(bothAreTrue){

}else if(bool1){

}else if(bool2){

}else{ //none is true

}
```

Comment: How this makes things easier? You still have the same number of conditions so just one less, but with one more variable used.

Comment: Variable are for readability (can of course be condensed) and I prefer not to nest multiple if-statements.

Comment: Wastage of memory. Variable `bothAreTrue` are created and used only at one place. Then why create it. It can be used as `if(bool1 && bool2)`

Comment: OK, I stand corrected :) How does it work on SO, can I just edit my post, or shall I leave it as is?

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with the "policy over implementation" philosophy (tell me *what* your code is doing not *how* it is doing it), you could make it read better by hiding the booleans a little:

```
public enum WhatBool1AndBool2ActuallyMean
{
    WhatItMeansWhenBothAreTrue,
    WhatItMeansWhenOnlyBool1IsTrue,
    WhatItMeansWhenOnlyBool2IsTrue,
    WhatItMeansWhenNeitherAreTrue
}

public WhatBool1AndBool2ActuallyMean GrokMeaning(bool bool1, bool bool2) {...}

...

WhatBool1AndBool2ActuallyMean meaning = GrokMeaning(bool1, bool2);
switch(meaning)
{
   case WhatBool1AndBool2ActuallyMean.WhatItMeansWhenBothAreTrue:
       ...
       break;
   case...
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. In some cases this may make sense, but in others it would probably just over complicate things. At least one case I can see this being more intuitive is spatial partitioning of a set of points into an Octree.

Comment: Obviously, I value readability and maintainability.  Sure, there's more plumbing code, but when someone needs to figure out why something is or isn't happening they don't have to decode what those dueling booleans mean.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest this condition could be written as ..

```
if (bool1)
{
}

if (bool2)
{
}
```

as the second condition will execute regardless of the result of the first condition. Can you explain you issue with more context, or give a real world example ?

Tim

Comment: Have a look at the questions code again. It is testing for 4 different outcomes. `true true`, `true false`, `false false`, `false true`. I think it is implied that each outcome will do something different.